# How to identify more than 10 faces in Microsoft Face API

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

According to this doc: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395239

Only 10 faces can be identified even after having more than 10 faces in 'Person Groups'
Is there any way we can increase the limit?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation you pointed at says:

```
The algorithm allows more than one face to be identified independently at the same request, but no more than 10 faces.
```

There is no way to increase this limit. It is a "by request" limit, so you just have to do several requests in parallel to solve this.

Comment: Just take into consideration the API has a rate limit as well so depending on your implementation and requirements might be better to do batches of 10 in sequence.